# Z^m number system in Rust

Tags: mathematics, rust

A \$Z^m\$ number system includes integers in the interval \$[0, m)\$ when \$m > 0\$ or \$(m, 0]\$ when \$m < 0\$. The code defines a trait `Mod` to represent numbers in this system and the `+`, `-`, and `*` operator for it.

```
use std::ops::Add;
use std::ops::Mul;
use std::ops::Sub;

struct Mod<T: Modulo<T>> {
    modulo: T,
    i: T,
}

trait Modulo<T> {
    fn modulo(&self, n: T) -> T;
}

impl Modulo<i32> for i32 {
    fn modulo(&self, n: i32) -> i32 {
        let mut x: i32 = *self;
        while x.signum() != n.signum() {
            x += n;
        }
        x % n
    }
}

impl Mod<i32> {
    fn new(modulo: i32, i: i32) -> Mod<i32> {
        let n = i.modulo(modulo);
        Mod {
            modulo: modulo,
            i: n,
        }
    }
}

impl Add for Mod<i32> {
    type Output = Mod<i32>;
    fn add(self, other: Mod<i32>) -> Mod<i32> {
        Mod::new(self.modulo, self.i + other.i)
    }
}

impl Sub for Mod<i32> {
    type Output = Mod<i32>;
    fn sub(self, other: Mod<i32>) -> Mod<i32> {
        Mod::new(self.modulo, self.i - other.i)
    }
}

impl Mul for Mod<i32> {
    type Output = Mod<i32>;
    fn mul(self, other: Mod<i32>) -> Mod<i32> {
        Mod::new(self.modulo, self.i * other.i)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = Mod::new(-5, 3);
    let y = Mod::new(-5, 8);
    println!("{}", (x + y).i);
    let x = Mod::new(-5, 3);
    let y = Mod::new(-5, 8);
    println!("{}", (x - y).i);
    let x = Mod::new(-5, 3);
    let y = Mod::new(-5, 8);
    println!("{}", (x * y).i);
}
```

All suggestions are welcome, but I am particularly interested in:

- Extending to `u32`, `u16`, `u8`, `i16`, `i8` etc without too much code duplication.
- Increasing performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would hesitate to implement `Mod<T> * Mod<T>`, and instead implement `Mod<T> * T` (and vice-versa). This is because you make no attempt to preserve the rhs' modulo, so you probably shouldn't have one there.

Consider the code

```
let mut x: i32 = *self;
while x.signum() != n.signum() {
    x += n;
}
x % n
```

That `while` loop makes this operation \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$, whereas a simpler implementation

```
((x % n) + n) % n
```

is \$\mathcal{O}(1)\$.

Performance elsewhere is probably uninteresting, since it devolves to basic integer operations.

Extending to other `T` should probably be done by being generic over the `Mod` and `Add` traits, as well as whatever particular operation is needed to implement. Something like

```
impl<T> Sub<T> for Mod<T>
    where T: Add<T> + Mod<T> + Sub<T>
{
    type Output = Mod<T>;
    fn sub(self, other: T) -> Mod<T> {
        Mod::new(self.modulo, self.i - i)
    }
}
```

The `Add` and `Mod` are needed by `Mod::new`, the `Sub` is needed inside the `sub` call.

Comment: Wouldn't `(x % n) + n` suffice?

Comment: Actually it has to be `((x % n) + n) % n`, I don't quite understand why, thought.

Comment: Rust's `%` corresponds to remainder, not modulus. http://stackoverflow.com/a/13683709/1763356